# Java code exits without return to calling script

Tags: java, exit, aix

We are trying to diagnose the cause of a problem with Java code (JRE7) run on an AIX6 system.  High-level overview is that SCRIPTA.sh executes java, passing the class MyJava1.  The script contains this:

```
exec 1>/our/log/file
exec 2>&1
echo "Java tool execution began at $(date '+%Y-%m-%d %T')"
/path/to/java -cp $CLASSPATH:support_stuff.jar the_tool > $TEMPFILE 2>&1
echo "Java tool execution ended at $(date '+%Y-%m-%d %T')"
...
```

The process runs for about 30 seconds, then returns, after which our log file contains the message "Java tool execution began...", and nothing after that.  Notably, the "Java tool execution ended" message is never written to the log, and none of the other code after that is executed.

So with all that said, what might we look for in Java source that could cause such a catastrophic exit?

Thanks

Comment: Please post java code in question itself

Comment: The code is proprietary and complex, involving a significant number of classes and jar files.  It is actually an Oracle "upload tool" for their Cloud, and may or may not have customization (looks like I am inheriting this, but details are sketchy).  So unfortunately I must keep the discussion high level and generic for now.  The folder containing the source is huge, and as a starting point I am looking for things I might 'grep' for to identify potential areas.  Since it's unusual for java to NOT return to the caller, hoped this might be a good place to start.

Comment: Java is not a command line tool that always exits. It depends on how it was designed.

Comment: So how did you verified the exit? Did you tried to start it manualy in the command line?

Comment: As for how I verified that it exited: The script that executed it (run from a process scheduler) ended, and its process no longer shows up in a process list.

Comment: @Dennis Was anything written to `$TEMPFILE`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention.  Nothing was written to $TEMPFILE.  It was created, and empty.